# Chagnes done to the rootfs do not redirect to the overlay set in fstab

Tags: fstab, root-filesystem, readonly, overlayfs

The fstab is a link to the next fstab file:

```
# <file system> <mount pt> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
/dev/root       /          ext2   ro,noauto 0       1
proc            /proc      proc   defaults  0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p10 /data      ext4   defaults  0       0
overlay         /          overlay
lowerdir=/,upperdir=/data/rfs_overlay,workdir=/data/rfs_overlay_work 0 0
```

the overlay does not take effect using the fstab and the mount command output does no contain any overlay line.

I tried changing the fstab line to :

```
# <file system> <mount pt>         <type>  <options> <dump> <pass>
overlay         /data/rfs_overlay  overlay
lowerdir=/,upperdir=/data/rfs_overlay_upper,workdir=/data/rfs_overlay_work 0 0
```

Then, I get that line from the mount command :

```
overlay on /data/rfs_overlay type overlay
(rw,relatime,lowerdir=/,upperdir=/data/rfs_overlay_upper,workdir=/data/rfs_overlay_work)
```

However, when i try to create test.txt file in the rootfs I get the folowing resopnse:

```
touch test.txt
touch: test.txt: Read-only file system
```

It is to be noticed that if I change the rootfs to rw and than create the file on the rootfs, the file is created both in the roofs and in the overlay:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
touch test.txt
find / -name test.txt
/data/rfs_overlay/root/test.txt /root/test.txt
```

I tried the following links with no success:

- [askubuntu.com/questions/821733/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821733/)
- [community.toradex.com/t/automount-overlay-for-etc/15529](https://community.toradex.com/t/automount-overlay-for-etc/15529)
- [wiki.archlinux.org/title/Overlay_filesystem](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Overlay_filesystem)
- [superuser.com/questions/1507278/](https://superuser.com/questions/1507278/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to understand what happens in the second try.

```
# <file system> <mount pt>         <type>  <options> <dump> <pass>
overlay         /data/rfs_overlay  overlay
lowerdir=/,upperdir=/data/rfs_overlay_upper,workdir=/data/rfs_overlay_work 0 0
```

- Your lowerdir it `/`. The lowerdir is supposed to be static and should be readonly. You can think of this directory as the "base". Those are the initial unchanged files.
- You upper dir is `/data/rfs_overlay_upper`. This is the folder that's supposed to hold the changes, or the "delta" from the lowerdir.
- And your mount point in this case is `/data/rfs_overlay`. This means that this mount would be the result of the merge between your lowerdir (the "base" - `/`) and upperdir (the "delta" - `/data/rfs_overlay_upper`).

For instance, in your case, if you create a the file `/data/rfs_overlay/afile`, you will see it's created in the upperdir: `/data/rfs_overlay_upper/afile`. That's how the lowerdir remains unchanged, and the upperdir contains the "delta" - the changes between the lowerdir and the merged folder.

In your case, you made the change in `/`, which is the lowerdir for `/data/rfs_overlay`. As I said before, the lowerdir is supposed to remain static (that's why it was r/o). You shouldn't touch the lowerdir no the upperdir, only the merged mount. The kernel should make any change to the upperdir.

So that's the explanation for what happened to you in the second try.

Regarding you initial attempt. First of all, you're trying to mount `/` twice, which isn't possible.

In theory you first need to mount the partition(s) that include(s) the lower, upper and work dirs. And then at the end you need to mount your merged destination path.

But in your case, I don't think it can work either way. You want your merged folder to be `/` (so according to what I said, it needs to be mounted **after** the lower/upper/work dirs), but also the root filesystem has to be the first one to be mounted! Because the rest of the mounts should be mounted on it. So that's the reason it isn't possible.

I assume you're goal is to have some sort of "snapshot" for the rootfs, to keep it static and to make all the changes be written to an upper dir. If that's what you're trying to do, I suggest you use some Copy-On-Write filesystem that supports snapshots for your root fs, such as [btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) or [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS). Of course you'll need to reinstall your host for that. But you cannot use overlay the way you want to.

Comment: tnx very much for u'r answer